# Copy an object with a form in a django CBV

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a Django function-based-view that copies a model object using a ModelForm

```
def my_model_copy(request, object_id):
    new_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=object_id)
    new_object.pk = None  # autogen a new primary key (object_id by default)
    # some other unique fields that need updating
    new_object.import_id = uuid.uuid4()  
    new_object.name = new_object.name + " - COPY"

    form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=new_object)

    # lots more code I am repeating in MyModelCreateView()
```

I'm trying to update this to use my `CreateView` CBV to DRY out my code, but where do I set the initial instance of the object?  I tried a couple places:

**overriding `get()`**

```
class MyModelCopyView(MyModelCreateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # Not the right place... Where to put this code?
        super_response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # make a copy of the object
        new_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=self.kwargs['object_id'])
        new_object.pk = None  # autogen a new primary key (object_id by default)
        # some other unique fields that need updating
        new_object.import_id = uuid.uuid4()  
        new_object.name = new_object.name + " - COPY"

        return super_response
```

**overriding `get_form()`**

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)

    # make a copy of the object
    new_object = get_object_or_404(MyModel, pk=self.kwargs['object_id'])
    new_object.pk = None  # autogen a new primary key (object_id by default)
    # some other unique fields that need updating
    new_object.import_id = uuid.uuid4()  
    new_object.name = new_object.name + " - COPY"

    form.instance = new_quest

    return form
```

But... these don't work.  The form isn't seeded with `new_object`

Alternately, I could inherit from `MyModelUpdateView()` instead, starting with the pk of a the object to be copied, but then I need to know where/how to make it a copy/new object instead of just updating the original object.

Answer (score 0):

## provide the initial dictionary data rather than the object.

```
class MyModelCopyView(MyModelCreateView):
    # pass your codes
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = {}
        pk = self.kwargs.get('object_id')
        if pk:
            # need to cast object to dictionary
            obj = MyModel.objects.filter(pk=pk).values()
            if obj:
                d = obj[0]
                d.pop('id')
                initial.update(d)
                # handle data here
        return initial
```